# Getting error Error: Unknown property 'mypostApi1.cls_data'

Tags: apex, visualforce, callout

I am making a callout and the received answers I want to show on the VF page

here is my code

**Callout**

```
public class mypostApicallout {

public static mypostApi1 fetchmynewapi()
    {
        http htp = new http();
        HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res= new HttpResponse();
        req.setEndpoint('https://gorest.co.in/public-api/posts');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        res=htp.send(req);
        string jsonstr= res.getBody();
        system.debug('jsinstr-->'+jsonstr);// data coming till here
         mypostApi1 model= (mypostApi1)json.deserialize(jsonstr, mypostApi1.class);
     
         system.debug('my model is-->'+model);
         system.debug('my code is-->'+model.code);
          system.debug('my data is-->'+model.data);
          // mypostApi1.cls_data[] clist=model.data;
           return model;          
        
    }

}
```

**Wrapper Class is:**

```
public class mypostApi1{
    public Integer code {get;set;}//200
    public cls_meta meta;
    //public cls_data[] data {get;set;}
    public list<cls_data> data {set;get;}
    public class cls_meta {
        public cls_pagination pagination;
    }
    class cls_pagination {
        public Integer total;   //1322
        public Integer pages;   //67
        public Integer page;    //1
        //public Integer limit; //20
    }
    public class cls_data {
        public Integer id {get;set;}    
        public Integer user_id {get;set;}   
        public String title {get;set;}  
        public String body {get;set;}   
        public String created_at {get;set;} //2021-02-18T03:50:03.993+05:30
        public String updated_at {get;set;} //2021-02-18T03:50:03.993+05:30
    }
    public static mypostApi1 parse(String json){
        return (mypostApi1) System.JSON.deserialize(json, mypostApi1.class);
    }

}
```

**VF Page CODE**

```
<apex:page controller="myapivfpage">
   <apex:form >
       <apex:pageblock >
      <apex:pageblockTable value="{!newmodel.cls_data}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.title}"/>    // if I print newmodel  data is there on VF just not 
                                               getting inside cls_Data list  Error: Unknown property 
 'mypostApi1.cls_data'
            
      </apex:pageblockTable>
  </apex:pageblock>
  
  <apex:commandButton value="click me" action="{!clickme}"/>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**COntroller**

```
public class myapivfpage {

public mypostApi1 newmodel {set;get;}

public pagereference clickme()
   {
      newmodel=mypostApicallout.fetchmynewapi();
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: `value="{!newmodel.cls_data}"` should be `value="{!newmodel.data}"` for the page block table. What happens when you do that?

Comment: Perfect issues resolved, I tried this earlier also but at that time not working, now its working , thanks for quick help